# How does IBM MQ's guaranteed delivery work

Tags: transactions, ibm-mq, messaging, soa, banking

Let's suppose 2 banking systems (let them be A and B) use IBM MQ to communicate with each other by sending messages, assume a scenario there is RecordA at A and RecordB is at B. When a transaction is initiated where RecordA needs to be updated if and only RecordB is updated. How does MQ achieve that?

For example, a fund transfer that deducts 100USD from the AccountA at A and adds 100USD to the AccountB at B,

One possibility is:
A first initiate the transaction and send a message to B and once MQ guarantees the delivery of the message, it performs the deduction at which point B would also have performed the addition. What if MQ fails to guarantee the delivery of the message while actually it might have been delivered? What would A do in that case? (one scenario where that would happen is that the message gets delivered but the acknowledgement gets lost in transit due to a failure of the communication medium, of course we can acknowledge the acknowledgement but the same problem appears again)

I can't imagine a solution to that problem which IBM MQ is supposedly using. What am I missing? Does a solution exist for the problem?

Comment: IBM MQ provides assured delivery but stops short of calling it guaranteed delivery.   This is only possible with persistent messages.   Persistent messages are written to disk at each hop with confirmation between MQ servers.

Answer (score 0):

MQ doesn't really operate with acknowledgments, but rather transactions.
To mitigate the problem you described, you need to do something like this on B:

1. Get message under syncpoint
2. Process transfer
3. Commit message
4. Commit transfer on your system

So this way, if MQ fails before you commit getting the message, you can roll back your local processing. (And the same way, if your local processing fails, getting the message can be rolled back.) And after MQ recovers, you can try processing the message again (provided it was a persistent message).

And of course, A needs to send the transfer in a similar fashion, so your local changes are always kept in line with putting/getting messages. And while the message is on MQ, MQ guarantees exactly once delivery.

To further improve transaction handling, MQ also supports XA coordinated transactions. So you can start a coordinated transaction between the QM and your application, making sure that transactions for putting/getting messages and changing DBs for example are committed or rolled back at the same time.